# Unable to click on Linkify elements

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog, spannablestring, linkify

I am very new to android programming and have been brought onboard to help finish a project. I am trying to create an alert that contains links to phone numbers and to addresses that when clicked, will launch the dialer and default maps app respectively.

Right now my current approach:

```
Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
AlertDialog ad = builder.Create();
ad.SetTitle("Quick Info");

var alertMsg = "";
alertMsg += "Address: " + addressString;
alertMsg += "\nPhone Number: " + phoneString;
SpannableString linkedMsg = new SpannableString(alertMsg);
Linkify.AddLinks(linkedMsg, MatchOptions.All);
ad.SetMessage(linkedMsg);
ad.SetButton("OK", (s, er) => { });
ad.Show();
```

Seems to work as it recognizes both the phone number and address as links (highlights them and underlines them) but when I attempt to click on them nothing happens. I feel like I am missing maybe a simple property or something to say that I am allowed to click, but I can't seem to find anything!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

```
Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = newAlertDialog.Builder(activity);
AlertDialog ad = builder.Create();
ad.SetTitle("Quick Info");

var alertMsg = "";
alertMsg += "Address: " + addressString;
alertMsg += "\nPhone Number: " + phoneString;
SpannableString linkedMsg = new SpannableString(alertMsg);
Linkify.AddLinks(linkedMsg, MatchOptions.All);
ad.SetMessage(linkedMsg);
ad.SetButton("OK", (s, er) => { });
ad.Show();

// major key    
((TextView)ad.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Message)).MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
```